# Error: add item to ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, addition, logcat

Method of add gives error for `ArrayList`. It isn't adding.

```
    public List<String> arrayList;

...

arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

...

savenumberButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String str = numberText.getText().toString();
            Integer cout = listView.getCount()+ 1;
            String str1 = cout.toString().concat("."+str);

            try {
                arrayList.add(listView.getCount(), str1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("Error", "arraylist.add is not running!");
            }

            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            blockNumberText.setText(" ");
        }
    });

...
```

Comment: Might need to use `arrayList.add(listView.getCount() - 1, str1);`

Comment: What is the returned data type of listView.getCount()?

Comment: Two things: tell us what the error is, and tell us what listView is.

Comment: Call e.printStackTrace() on catch block and publish logs from error

Comment: ... W/System.err﹕ java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
... W/System.err﹕ at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
... W/System.err﹕ at com......MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:78)
... W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
... W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now that you have posted the exception and line number and more details in the comments, this seems be because when you call `asList()`
This method "Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.." then you just cast it to an `ArrayList`which is incorrect.

so the method `add` throws the `UnsupportedOperationException` because the `List` has a fixed size and cannot be modified.

instead try

```
arrayList = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(number, ",")));
```

Comment: I didn't understand an index that already exists. Could you please explain it?

Comment: That's not the error you are getting but if you have an ArrayList like <item0,item1,item2,item3> and you call ArrayList.add(5, item4), you will get an IndexOutOfBounds Exception.

Comment: Line 78 is arrayList.add(listView.getCount() - 1, str1);

Comment: I just changed as the AbstractList but same line is problem W/System.err﹕ at .....MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:79)

Comment: AbstractList is not the right class. It is an Abstract class and is meant to be extended by other classes and the methods are implemented there. Use ArrayList

Comment: Okey but there is problem another line:         String number = sharedPref.getString("List", null);
        arrayList = (ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(number, ","));

Comment: Your solution is okey but it can't add item to ArrayList.